# Dataframe from nested dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a dataframe as below from the dictionary `"user_dict"`. I used a for loop to achieve this. Is there a better way to achieve the same result?

```py
import pandas as pd

user_dict = {12: {'Category 1': {'att_1': 1, 'att_2': 'whatever'},
                  'Category 2': {'att_1': 23, 'att_2': 'another'}},
             15: {'Category 1': {'att_1': 10, 'att_2': 'foo'},
                  'Category 2': {'att_1': 30, 'att_2': 'bar'}}}

mydict = {"level1": [], "level2": [], "att_1": [], "att_2": [] }

for level1key, leve1value in user_dict.items() :
     for level2key, level2value in leve1value.items():
          mydict["level1"].append(level1key)
          mydict["level2"].append(level2key)
          for level3key, level3value in level2value.items():
             if level3key == "att_1": 
               mydict["att_1"].append(level3value)
             else:
               mydict["att_2"].append(level3value)

df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)
print(df)

   level1      level2  att_1     att_2
0      12  Category 1      1  whatever
1      12  Category 2     23   another
2      15  Category 1     10       foo
3      15  Category 2     30       bar
```

Comment: The accepted answer from the suggested duplicate (using the *exact same* `user_dict`) will do it; just chain [`.reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), and maybe [`.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) if you really want `level1, 2` instead of `level_0, _1`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
pd.DataFrame(user_dict).stack().apply(pd.Series).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
      level_0  level_1  att_1     att_2
0  Category 1       12      1  whatever
1  Category 1       15     10       foo
2  Category 2       12     23   another
3  Category 2       15     30       bar
```

Steps:

1. Create a basic dataframe using the dictionary
2. Stack all of the columns into one long column
3. `pd.Series turns all of the elements of each row into it's own value in a different column
4. Reset the index, so it's no longer grouped